# SQL date query for product rate change

Tags: sql, datetime

Below is by Dataset

```
CREATE TABLE [testRateChange]
(
[dt] [datetime] NULL,
[Rate] [int] NULL
)

 
--Insert Data
INSERT INTO [testRateChange](dt,Rate)
VALUES
('2014-09-18 06:25:19.897', 270),
('2014-09-19 06:25:19.897', 270),
('2014-09-20 06:25:19.897', 310),
('2014-09-21 06:25:19.897', 310),
('2014-09-22 06:25:19.897', 310),
('2014-09-23 06:25:19.897', 320),
('2014-09-24 06:25:19.897', 310),
('2014-09-25 06:25:19.897', 320),
('2014-09-26 06:25:19.897', 270)
```

and I need output like below

```
Start Date  End Date    Rate
18/9/2020   19/9/2020   270
20/9/2020   22/9/2020   310
23/9/2020   23/9/2020   320
24/9/2020   24/9/2020   310
25/9/2020   25/9/2020   320
26/9/2020   26/9/2020   270
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Most support `LAG()` which is likely what is needed here.

Comment: ...and the above SQL is product specific in several ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
with transitions as (
    select *, case when rate <> lag(rate) over(order by dt) then 1 end as flag
    from testRateChange
), runs as (
    select *, count(flag) over (order by dt) as counter
    from transitions
)
select min(dt), max(dt), min(rate)
from runs
group by counter;
```